# python or colab not recognizing the or operator

Tags: python

colab or python ide is not recognize the or statement. If I run one statement, it checks and prompts me to enter the correct one. but if I  add the next expression with the "or operator", it just keeps prompting me for the correct info even when its correct.

```
salesperson_num = input ("Please enter the salesperson's ID number: ")
sales_amt = float (input ("Please enter sales amount: "))
class_type = int (input ("Please enter a class type for the salesperson: "))

while class_type !=1 or class_type !=2:
    class_type = int(input("Please enter class a correct class: Class 1 , 2: "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use logic and to indicate that it is neither 1 nor 2:

```
while class_type != 1 and class_type != 2:
    ...
```

This is equivalent to:

```
while not (class_type == 1 or class_type == 2):
    ...
```

Comment: what if i wanted to test if they are true, it was still not recognizing both expression. only when i add 1. so
 while class_type == 1 or class_type == 2:
         print("You are a sales person)

Comment: @CONRADINEPOWELL Can you update your question and explain your new question with specific code?